# Twisted, how to "putChild()" with trailing slash?

Tags: python, twisted

Im using twisted, and made a webserver, but when i try to request a page with a trailing slash i get

"No Such Resource - No such child resource."

I tried all of these

```
    self.putChild('login', Login(self))
    self.putChild('/login/', Login(self))
    self.putChild('/login', Login(self))
    self.putChild('login/', Login(self))
```

Even tried overriding the 'getChildWithDefault' method, and tried requesting pages with both slashes and no slash, and it always say the path is 'login', no slashes, so it should always match the first line, but doesn't for w.e reason.

Anyone know how to add a child resource with the trailing slash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass a slash to `putChild`; it will be escaped by the URL traversal logic, because the argument is a single path segment.

Assuming that `Login` is itself a `Resource` though, you can put *itself* onto itself, so that both `/login` and `/login/` will work, like so:

```
l = Login(self)
l.putChild("", l)
self.putChild("login", l)
```

You can of course make `/login` without the trailing slash a resource of your own design, or a [`twisted.web.util.Redirect`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.4.0/api/twisted.web.util.Redirect.html) that adds a slash; assemble your resources in whichever configuration you prefer :).

Comment: Thanks! I added `self.putChild("",self)` to the `__init__` of `Login`, and now it works the way i like, i might make a subclass like that, and use that as my Resource for pages i want like this.

Comment: If you are writing your own `Resource` class, you might want to just implement `getChild` to deal with `""` properly, rather than relying on `putChild`.  `putChild` is mostly for arranging static collections of resources that have no other way to know about each other, but in your case, `Login` knows that it should always be its own empty-segment child…